# Multiple search strings with re and gspread

Tags: python, gspread, python-re

I've just started using gspread and looking for some advice on searching a sheet. I want to search for multiple strings and get the results of the specific row where both strings exist. Both strings must match for a result (logical AND)

An example of the search string would be to search for an IP Address, AND hostname. In the sheet the IP address would be in cell A1 and Hostname would be in B1.

I'm using the below code example from their documentation and have tried various iterations but not having much luck.

```
amount_re = re.compile(r'(192.168.0.1|Gi0/0.100)')
cell = worksheet.find(amount_re)
```

[Gspread documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

Here is the format of the data:

```
192.168.0.1,Gi0/0.100
192.168.0.1,Gi0/0.200
192.168.0.1,Gi0/0.300
192.168.0.2,Gi0/0.100
```

As you can see there are duplicates in A and B column so the only way to get a unique results is to search for both. e.g.

```
192.168.0.1,Gi0/0.100
```

It needs to be in the Gspread search format though. I can't just search for the string '192.168.0.1,Gi0/0.100'

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? From your question, I could understand that the string values for searching are put in the cells "A1:B1". Can I ask you about the information of data you want to search? Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about it from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this.

Comment: I have updated the question. The only way I can get a 'unique' result is to search for two strings because there are duplicates in column A and B.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. About `the results of the specific row where both strings exist.`, you want to retrieve the values of cells of searched rows? Or you want to retrieve the row number of the searched rows? Which do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Thanks. Really I just want to see if that search match is in the Google sheet.  But to be able to get the row number and cell data would also be useful. For background, I have my script working now using local csv. It does audit of network devices, when finished on a device it adds an entry to csv. Later when I re-run, it iterates and searches in csv `if search_str in entry` If it exists then it skips that entry. The search string in csv would be e.g. _192.168.0.1,Gi0/0.100_  Now I want to migrate to sheets and gspread and do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and question, I proposed the sample scripts of 2 patterns as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal like below.

- You want to search 2 values like `192.168.0.1` and `Gi0/0.100` from a sheet in a Google Spreadsheet.
- The 2 values are to the columns "A" and "B".
- When 2 values like `192.168.0.1` and `Gi0/0.100` are found at the same row, you want to retrieve the values.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.
- You have alredy been get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

For achieving your goal, how about this answer?

I think that unfortunately, `re.compile(r'(192.168.0.1|Gi0/0.100)')` cannot be used for achieving your goal. So here, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values are searched using the Query Language. The access token can be used from the authorization for gspread.

#### Sample script:

```
searchValues = ["192.168.0.1", "Gi0/0.100"]  # Please set the search values.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
ss = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
ws = ss.worksheet(sheetName)
sheet_id = ws._properties['sheetId']
access_token = client.auth.token_response['access_token']
query = "select * where A='" + \
    searchValues[0] + "' and B='" + searchValues[1] + "'"
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + \
    spreadsheet_id + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + \
    str(sheet_id) + '&tq=' + urllib.parse.quote(query)
res = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token})
ar = [row for row in csv.reader(io.StringIO(res.text), delimiter=',')]
print(ar)
```

- In this case, when the search values are found, `ar` has the searched rows. When the search values are NOT found, the length of `ar` is `0`.
- In this case, the row index cannot be retrieved.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, at first, all values are retrieved from the worksheet, and the values are searched.

#### Sample script:

```
searchValues = ["192.168.0.1", "Gi0/0.100"]  # Please set the search values.
spreadsheet_id = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1"  # Please set the sheet name.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
ss = client.open_by_key(spreadsheet_id)
ws = ss.worksheet(sheetName)
values = ws.get_all_values()
ar = [{"rowIndex": i, "value": e} for i, e in enumerate(
    values) if e[0] == searchValues[0] and e[1] == searchValues[1]]
print(ar)
```

- In this case, when the search values are found, `ar` has the row index and values of the searched rows. When the search values are NOT found, the length of `ar` is `0`.
- In this case, the row index can be retrieved.

### References:

- [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [get_all_values()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-worksheet-as-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for taking the time to answer. It's exactly what I wanted. I had to get the ID of the sheet to use your example. How come I needed the ID in your example but in my code I never had an ID? `scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds`,`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']` 'creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('xxxxxxxx.json', scope)` `client = gspread.authorize(creds)` `sheet = client.open("Test").sheet1`

Comment: @tars01 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, unfortunately, I cannot understand. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for the help.